# Python and git, best way to know when a file has changed from a sync

Tags: python, git

I am using chef to fetch changes on my production servers once a minute and in the github repo I have 6 spawn-fcgi scripts under control of runit.  If only one of the files changes I need to restart runit to pick up the changes.  My pseudo code looks like this.

```
git fetch
for each file:
    if file changed from last sync:
       sv start myrunit
    else:
        pass
```

I am open to nay best practice method.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

```
git diff --name-only HEAD@{1}..HEAD
```

will list files changed between the previous and current checked-out commit.

Comment: How do I code around that?  If I have 100 files, 20 changed but I am only looking for file1.py that changed.

Comment: Then just run `git diff --name-only ... file1.py`.